# Windows Update something went wrong Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

As of a few days ago (Sept. 2020) I cannot install Windows 10 Updates anymore. When I go to “Windows Update” I always get this message.

“Something went wrong. Try to reopen Settings later.”

There is no Update button either.

What I tried unsuccessfully:

- I tried changing settings in the Registry around
  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU.
- I saw that there is a service running “StopUpdates10 Guard” by
  Greatis which I disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the `UsoSvc`, this service is essential for Windows updates to work. Ppen regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsoSvc
```

In the right pane locate "start" and right click on it. Select modify in the value data box that opens, change 4 to 2, restart computer and try updates now. The default setting for this key is 2 which equates to automatic start 4 disables the service.